# Overlay with jQuery Tools : working but not content with .load method

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I'm trying to make work something quite simple when I read the doc : opening a external URL into an overlay. I choose jQuery Tools overlay because I'm using other tools from flowplayer

After some tries and changes, the overlay itself is working(I can see the div opening with a nice apple effect).

But there is no content inside the div.

I checked : `this.getTrigger().attr("href")` returning the correct URL.

For me, it's just that the `owrap.load` doesn't work. I'm not very familiar with Ajax.

You could check the [page](http://infoglam.exigences.biz/) (the overlay is triggered by the button to the right, just above the picture of a couple). First, I display for checking the URL of the external

I also prepared a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veN3f/) but it's not working at all !

I made several searches (that allow me to correct some details) but now I don't how to even debug this. No error in console.

I have tried to change the way the code is finding the div, with no success so far, I'm not sure where the problem is.

**UPDATE:**

Using console.log, I can see that the request is working (200 OK), but no HTML. I tried other urls to be sure, it's the same.

Comment: Looking at the URL for the page you linked, and the URL that is shown when clicking on the button, you may be experiencing problems due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - it might be worth looking into changing where you get the data from, or the format you receive it in, if possible.

Comment: I tried with a page from the same domain, with no difference (no content).

Comment: No, I have to say you provide the right answer. I reloaded one more time and this time, i have the content (I was linking to the homepage). If I put back another URL from another domain, blank content again. I wasn't aware that same origin policy applied to jQuery Ajax ? Anyway, I could foresee a workaround, thank you. Please add your comment as answer so I could validate it. Simon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the URL for the page you linked, and the URL that is shown when clicking on the button, you may be experiencing problems due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) - it might be worth looking into changing where you get the data from, or the format you receive it in, if possible.